# Deserialize JSON string that supposed for object as string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to serialize a string of JSON. But inside this string, it contains objects that I want to serialize as a string.

Look at this JSON string

```
{
    "action":"applyPromo",
    "params":
    [
        {
            "transacId":"M123238831",
            "promotionId":16,
            "promotionTypeId":1,
            "amount":100,
            "transacTime":"2021-03-19T12:00:30.045+10:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since the action can be anything, I need to store the **params** as a string which will be deserialized elsewhere.

Here is my class:

```
public class RequestAction
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string params { get; set; }

    public RequestAction()
    {
        action = params = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

When I tried to deserialize the string using JSON (Newtonsoft), I got this error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'params', line 1, position 27.'`.

Here is my code to deserialize the JSON String

```
public static RequestAction Parse(str)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestAction>(str);
}
```

Any idea how to deserialize `params` as string?

Comment: Looks like your params property is an array of objects. Would it work to have the `params` prop as an `IEnumerable<string>` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need the `params` property as raw string. One way to achieve this is to use a [JToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm):

```
public class RequestAction
{
    public string Action { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public JToken Params { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Good solution:**

If you want to preserve the json structure, you can change type to `JToken`. Then Newtonsoft.Json will store raw json there and you will not lose any information on transformations.

**Alternative solution:**

You can implement custom json converter.

```
public class ObjectTostringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override string ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        return data.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(value);
    }
}
```

And mark properties to use this converter

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectTostringConverter))]
public string Params { get; set; }
```